# Using props as image source as well as setting cache

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to set the source of an Image component from the props passed to its parent while also setting force-cache for iOS. However, I can't seem to get the formatting proper and am receiving the error that 'this' is unexpected:
Unexpected keyword 'this'

This is how I'm trying to set the source for the Image:

```
<Image 
style = {[ styles.imageStyle, { resizeMode: this.props.resizeMode } ]} 
source = {{this.props.image, cache: 'force-cache'}} 
onLoad = { this.handleImageLoaded }/>
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here? Setting the Image source like

```
<Image source = { this.props.image }/>
```

works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code below, it seems to be an object. So you can try this.

```js
let imageData = this.props.image 
imageData.cache = 'force-cache'
...
<Image source = { imageData }/>
```